# BeautifulSoup, Selenium, Python Data Extraction Problem With For Looping

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I need to loop on 'ul' tag as I show my script.
Any one can help me how to make it?
Thank you very much for your time.

here is my code:

As I said, I want to loop through UL tag which include at least 10 LI tag. And I want to extract LI tag's texts. But I couldnt find a way to loop inside that UL tag.

```
page_source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, features='html.parser')
searchResCon = soup.find('div', {'class':'search-results-container'})
followerCol = searchResCon.find('div', {'class':'ph0 pv2 artdeco-card mb2'})
searchList = followerCol.find('ul', {'class':'reusable-search__entity-result-list 
list-style-none'})
singleCon = searchList.find('li', {'class':'reusable-search__result-container'})

for li in searchList: #I want to loop at inside 'ul' tag which equal to searchList 
        #variable
        #that ul tag has at least 10 'li' tag. I want to iterate over 'ul'.


        #here is the information that I collect with their precise name and variables 
        inside 
        of 'ul' tag which these infos inside 'li' s.

        name = singleCon.find('span', {'aria-hidden':'true'}).get_text().strip()
        title = singleCon.find('div', {'class':'entity-result__primary-subtitle t-14 
        t-black t-normal'}).get_text().strip()
        location = singleCon.find('div', {'class':'entity-result__secondary-subtitle 
        t-14 t- normal'}).get_text().strip()
        hashtag = singleCon.find('p', {'class':'entity-result__summary entity 
        result__summary--2-lines t-12 t-black--light mb1'}).get_text().strip()
        follower = singleCon.find('span',{'class':'entity-result__simple-insight-text 
        entity- 
        result__simple-insight-text--small'}).get_text().strip()

        #I have list called contactsInfo and I am appending whole information to this 
        list.

        contactsInfo.append(f'-' * 30)
        contactsInfo.append('\n')
        contactsInfo.append(f'-' * 30)
        contactsInfo.append('\n')
        contactsInfo.append(f'Name: {name}')
        contactsInfo.append('\n')
        contactsInfo.append(f'Title: {title}')
        contactsInfo.append('\n')
        contactsInfo.append(f'Location: {location}')
        contactsInfo.append('\n')
        contactsInfo.append(f'Hashtag: {hashtag}')
        contactsInfo.append('\n')
        contactsInfo.append(f'Follower & Mutual: {follower}')
        contactsInfo.append('\n')
```

When I added find_all object to searchList variable, then soup raise me error like this;

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [242], in <cell line: 8>()
      6 singleCon = searchList.find_all('li', {'class':'reusable-search__result-container'})
      8 for li in singleCon:
---> 10     name = singleCon.find('span', {'aria-hidden':'true'}).get_text().strip()
     11     title = singleCon.find('div', {'class':'entity-result__primary-subtitle t-14 t-black t-normal'}).get_text().strip()
     12     location = singleCon.find('div', {'class':'entity-result__secondary-subtitle t-14 t-normal'}).get_text().strip()

File ~/Desktop/linkedin/emv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bs4/element.py:2289, in ResultSet.__getattr__(self, key)
   2287 def __getattr__(self, key):
   2288     """Raise a helpful exception to explain a common code fix."""
-> 2289     raise AttributeError(
   2290         "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
   2291     )

AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

Thank you very much for your time.

By the way I use Python 3.10 and jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0):

*Code and error message don't really fit together. Based on the message, it should rather look like this*

Use `li` to find your information, not `singleCon` that is still the `ResultSet` you are iterating for each `li`:

```
singleCon = searchList.find_all('li', {'class':'reusable-search__result-container'})
for li in singleCon:
    name = li.find('span', {'aria-hidden':'true'}).get_text().strip()
    title = li.find('div', {'class':'entity-result__primary-subtitle t-14 t-black t-normal'}).get_text().strip()
    location = li.find('div', {'class':'entity-result__secondary-subtitle t-14 t-normal'}).get_text().strip()
```